# Strip quotes from rule outcome in Xtext2

Tags: string, xtext

I have the following Xtext2 grammar:

```
Bibliography:
  macros += Macro*
;

Macro:
  "@string{" name = ID "=" value = LATEXSTRING "}"
;

terminal LATEXSTRING:
  '"' (!('"'))* '"' 
;
```

When parsing a the string

```
@string{ABBREV = "Some Long Text"}
```

and storing it in some object `macro` of type `Macro` it has the following values:

```
macro.name: ABBREV
macro.value: "Some Long Text"
```

both of type `String` (`EString`). I would like to have the value without quotes though. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register a value convert for the rule LATEXSTRING. According to the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#valueconverter), it should look like this:

```
@Inject
private LatexStringConverter latexStringConverter; 

@ValueConverter(rule = "LATEXSTRING")
public IValueConverter<String> converterForLatexString() {
  return latexStringConverter;
}
```

with

```
public class LatexStringConverter extends AbstractLexerBasedConverter<String> {
  @Override
  protected String toEscapedString(String value) {
    ..      
  }

  public String toValue(String string, INode node) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I also found some source code at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt/source/browse/com.google.eclipse.protobuf/src/com/google/eclipse/protobuf/?name=26c3a4fce05f&r=26c3a4fce05fa9a6ccf8322064f8876ece6e1e91 that shows how to apply it.